# How to move Socket.io io.on('connection') code another js file?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

**SITUATION** (MAIN QUESTION START is under)

Recently, I practice Node.js web hosting.

I generate folder with express-generator, like under.

```sh
$ express --view=pug # default jade, change pug
$ npm install

$ ls
app.js bin node_modules package.json public routes views
```

For Create new page named **chat.js**, in app.js

```js
var chatRouter = require('./routes/chat');

...

app.use('/chat', chatRouter);
```

and create `/views/chat.pug`, `/routes/chat.js` simply.

---

Now. I want to use socket.io.

Some sample codes leads me like under.

**1. change app.js**

```js
var app = express(); # express generate this line
app.io = require('socket.io')();

...

app.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('app.js connection');
});
```

**2. change ./bin/www**

```js
var server = http.createServer(app); # express generate this line
app.io.attach(server);
```

**3. change /views/chat.pug**

```html
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var io = socket();
        });
    </script>
```

When I run server with `sudo node ./bin/www` and connect page `http://www.sample.com/chat`, log `app.js connection` is comes out. Greatly.

**MAIN QUESTION START**

But, I want to seperate under codes NOT `app.js`, for example, `/routes/chat.js` or somewhere for make short `app.js`

```js
app.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('app.js connection');
});
```

I try like under, but it not works that I expected.
In `/routes/chat.js`

```js
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('chat.js connection'); # NOT COMES HERE
});
```

Please help me to avoid make `app.js` longer.

Comment: I type some piece of code, but If you need full source code, I'll change question codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bin, import another module and pass app to it

```js
// app.js
var app = express(); # express generate this line

app.io = require('socket.io')();
require('../new-file')(app)

// new-file.js
module.exports = (app) => {
   app.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      console.log('app.js connection');
   });  
}
```